# Counting Steps for Iterated Function with Ceiling Terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If I have the following iterated function:
$$
L_{i+1} = \left\lceil \frac{N}{\left\lceil \frac{N}{L_{i}} \right\rceil-1} \right\rceil, L_{0} = 1
$$

I am trying to find $k$ such that $L_{k} = N$.
Is there a way to derive a closed form expression for $k$ as a function of $N$ or an upper limit on $k$ which is tighter than $N$?

I tried to get an estimate of how $k$ increases as $N$ grows exponentially from $10^1 .. 10^q$ and it seems to have an order of $C(q)^{\log{q}}$ with $C(q)$ decreasing in $q$, but I could not find a way to prove it by using the ceiling inequality $\lceil x \rceil = y \rightarrow y-1 < x \leq y$. I am not very knowledgable with discrete maths, so I am asking if you have some ideas that can help with this nested ceiling expression.

**Edit:**
We know now that $k = \lceil 2\sqrt{N} - 1 \rceil$, so the question is how to get there from the iterated function?

Answer (score 0):

$k$ will be close to $2\sqrt N$.  When $L_i$ is less than $\sqrt N$, we have $L_{i+1}=L_i+1$.  When $L_i$ is well greater than $\sqrt N, \frac N{L_i}$ decreases by $1$ each time.  Each part takes about $\sqrt N$ steps.  The ceilings make it hard to do a solid analysis.

Comment: Thank you. I just got to a similar conclusion. More precisely $\lceil 2\sqrt{N} - 1 \rceil$.

Comment: Could you please explain why $L_{i+1} = L_i +1$ when $L_{i} < \sqrt{N}$?

Comment: I can't find an easy proof.  You need two pieces-one to show that $L_i$ is strictly increasing and one to show it doesn't increase by more than $1$.  The second half comes because the fraction doesn't change much for a change of $1$ in the denominator.  The first from the fact that $\lceil \frac N{L_i} \rceil-1$ is strictly less than $\frac N{L_i}$ but you have to show the outer divisions can't round up to the same thing.  That is where I am stuck.